# How to use Like in left outer join

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM pay_invoice_list p
LEFT outer JOIN paimentDetl d
on p.invoice_no= d.invoiceNo and p.invoice_no LIKE ' %$temp%'
ORDER BY iid DESC
```

This is my query. But it doesn't work correctly. The tow tables are not join properly. as well as the "Like" didn't work.

Comment: What do your tables look like? What is your expected vs actual result? Do you really want to only join rows with an invoice_no which contains '$temp' or do you want to filter the already joined result (i.e. `WHERE`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM pay_invoice_list p 
    LEFT outer JOIN paimentDetl d ON p.invoice_no = d.invoiceNo 
WHERE p.invoice_no LIKE ' %$temp%' 
ORDER BY iid DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM pay_invoice_list p
LEFT outer JOIN paimentDetl d
on p.invoice_no= d.invoiceNo 
Where p.invoice_no LIKE ' %$temp%'
ORDER BY iid DESC
```

All you needed to do is add WHERE to your query.

Comment: Ha, beaten by 8 seconds ! ;-)

Comment: @jeroen_de_schutter, that is what normally happens to me! Ha!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM pay_invoice_list p
LEFT outer JOIN paimentDetl d
on p.invoice_no= d.invoiceNo
where p.invoice_no LIKE ' %$temp%'
ORDER BY iid DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only filter in your `join` statement when you want to filter the right table of your `left outer join` *(here paimentDetl)*. When you want to filter your left table *(here pay_invoice_list)*, you should add your filter clause in the `where clause`.

```
SELECT *
FROM pay_invoice_list p
LEFT outer JOIN paimentDetl d ON p.invoice_no= d.invoiceNo
WHERE p.invoice_no LIKE '%$temp%'
ORDER BY iid DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Put p.invoice_no in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM pay_invoice_list p
LEFT outer JOIN paimentDetl d on p.invoice_no= d.invoiceNo 
WHERE p.invoice_no LIKE ' %$temp%'
ORDER BY iid DESC
```

This will return all records from pay_invoice_list where invoice_no LIKE ' %$temp%' and all records from  paimentDetl where the invoice number matches.